# Python Draw graph with percent of frequency distribution

Tags: python, plot

I'm using Python and have never used it before to draw a plot and was wondering if there's a way to do the following. I have a file containing a column with percents (of DNA methylation data). I would like to plot the distribution frequency (perhaps using bins of 10) to display the data. Is there any way to do this in python.

Comment: you dont describe your input very well ... are you at least able to get a numerical list of percentages from the file?  what have you tried so far.  if your question is "Can I do this in python?" the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib is the tool that you want to explore.  Here is a nice tutorial, try working through the examples in that tutorial.  http://bespokeblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/basic-data-plotting-with-matplotlib-part-3-histograms/

The tutorial includes installation of matplotlib in ubuntu. If you are using windows, you should download the installer from http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

If your RAW methylation data came in the form of `.idat` files (Illumina uses this), look at the `methylprep` python package (and its associated `methylcheck` package for doing plots).

For methylation data, most people plot samples as a `beta distribution` or `m_value plot` showing the percent methylation for each probe (but actually a fraction from 0 to 1, not actually a percent).

Use would be something like this:

```
CLI: `python -m methylprep process -d <folder_path_of_idats> --all`
python:
>>>import methylcheck
>>>df = methylcheck.load(<path>) # creates a pandas dataframe of all samples in the folder you are in, or path specified.
>>>methylcheck.sample_plot(df)
```

example of plot produced in jupyter notebook below

[image]

Comment: `.sample_plot` is an alias of `.beta_density_plot()` in `methylcheck` that is more intuitively named